# Performance issue stored procedure not compiled server side

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I developped an app with all the business logic in mysql stored procedures.

I'm worried about performance when I will have numerous users as stored procedures are not compiuled like in a oracle database.

Say when I'll scale to 1000 concurent users what are the best practices if I want to go on with stored procedures (as they are super efficient for security and business logic)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The non-compilation of the stored procedures is not an issue (direct SQL access would not compile the queries either).

To make sure your code scales well in the database side, make sure the queries are optimized and do the optimization against full real data (not a subset).